# how to set focus on the textbox on a dialog form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox on dialog form, I want to default focus on it once form load, but for some reason, it does not happen.
I have tried: Focus and form_load event and put focus method right after initialization of form.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You may call `Control.Focus()` method in  Dialog Form's `Activated` event handler or set Tab Index order or use `Select()` method.

Comment: nice, i never thought it was caused by tabindex, great help !!

Comment: Nope, it does not work on Activated event, but it does work on Shown - I just tested.

Comment: I use textbox.Select();. Work like charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 16):

Use Form Shown event instead Load. Control cannot get focus while form doesn't shown.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
   private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              textBox1.Focus();
        }
}
```

Comment: putting control.focus() in the form's Shown event works great.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to use `textBox1.Select();` ?

Comment: yes, i tried that, it did not work, then thanks to AVD, he helped me out

Answer (score 2):

You may also use the ActiveControl method of the dialog.  For example if you build the dialog form in your code like  [**Form dialog = new Form()**] then you would use the **dialog.ActiveControl =** "*Name of your control*".

Answer (score 1):

Try using textbox2.Select() in the load event of the dialog form.